# Data validation list run macro from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro (for a test just prompt a message box) from a data validation list which is created every time I run a macro which create a new line. The new row is created in row 6, and the data validation list is always in F6. 
When I add a new line this will offcourse change and move the old one down.

I want to run a new macro when any of the data validation lists are changed in column "F".

Right now I have this code, but it keeps prompting

"Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

My module creating the validation list looks like this:

```
With Range("F6").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="High,Medium,Low"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

And in sheet1 I have on change the following code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim d As Range
Set d = Application.Intersect(Target.Cells(1), Me.Range("F5:F1000"))
    If Not Range("F5:F1000") Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Columns(2)
            Case "High": MsgBox ("Test")
            Case "Medium": MsgBox ("Test")
            Case "Low": MsgBox ("Test")
        End Select
        Else
                    'do nothing
    End If
```

Can anyone spot the error?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcJIM.png)

-CP

Comment: a little bit confusing to me. would you mind clearing that up by adding: 1) the macro "concatenation" events along with their code 2) some Excel UI screenshots of relevant steps

Comment: Hi. What I need is a way to link the Module code (with the validation list) to the worksheet change cases. It can be any list, I just can't figure out how to link the list to the "select case" properly. I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you're after this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim d As Range

    Set d = Application.Intersect(Target.Cells(1), Range("F5:F1000")) 
    If Not d Is Nothing Then ' <<---check if set range is nothing
        Select Case Target.Value2 ' <<-- check changed cell (i.e. 'Target') value
            Case "High": MsgBox "High" & " in " & Target.Address
            Case "Medium": MsgBox "Medium" & " in " & Target.Address
            Case "Low": MsgBox "Low" & " in " & Target.Address
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```